# На IPhone с "чёлкой" (X, XR, 12 и т.п.) меню на сайте открывается само при прокрутке!

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery, bootstrap

Прикрепляю адрес сайта:
gojirra.store
Проблема скорее всего в css, но понять в чем конкретно я не могу.
Баг проявляется только на iPhone с чёлкой, вне зависимости от браузера.

Код вызова меню:

```
$(function() {
    $(document).on("click", ".mobile_menu_container .parent", function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(".mobile_menu_container .activity").removeClass("activity");
        $(this).siblings("ul").addClass("loaded").addClass("activity");
    });
    $(document).on("click", ".mobile_menu_container .back", function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(".mobile_menu_container .activity").removeClass("activity");
        $(this).parent().parent().removeClass("loaded");
        $(this).parent().parent().parent().parent().addClass("activity");
    });
    $(document).on("click", ".mobile_menu", function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(".mobile_menu_container").addClass("loaded");
        $(".mobile_menu_overlay").fadeIn();
    });
    $(document).on("click", ".mobile_menu_overlay", function(e) {
        $(".mobile_menu_container").removeClass("loaded");
        $(this).fadeOut(function() {
            $(".mobile_menu_container .loaded").removeClass("loaded");
            $(".mobile_menu_container .activity").removeClass("activity");
        });
    });
    $(document).on("click", ".offMenu", function(e) {
        $(".mobile_menu_container").removeClass("loaded");
        $(".mobile_menu_overlay").fadeOut(function() {
            $(".mobile_menu_container .loaded").removeClass("loaded");
            $(".mobile_menu_container .activity").removeClass("activity");
        });

    });
})
```

Comment: А еще горизонтальный скролл на пк, стоит исправить)) И проблема скорее всего в скрипте - так как появление меню, это все-таки скрипты. Как ты конкретно его вызываешь, продемонстрируй код.

Comment: Код добавил, спасибо за отзывчивость :)

Answer (score 0):

Возможно в айфонах как-то не так работает событие клик... Попробуй сделать событие на самом элементе, а не документе

```js
$(function() {
  $(".mobile_menu_container .parent").on("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(".mobile_menu_container .activity").removeClass("activity");
    $(this).siblings("ul").addClass("loaded").addClass("activity");
  });
  $(".mobile_menu_container .back").on("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(".mobile_menu_container .activity").removeClass("activity");
    $(this).parent().parent().removeClass("loaded");
    $(this).parent().parent().parent().parent().addClass("activity");
  });
  $(".mobile_menu").on("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(".mobile_menu_container").addClass("loaded");
    $(".mobile_menu_overlay").fadeIn();
  });
  $(".mobile_menu_overlay").on("click", function(e) {
    $(".mobile_menu_container").removeClass("loaded");
    $(this).fadeOut(function() {
      $(".mobile_menu_container .loaded").removeClass("loaded");
      $(".mobile_menu_container .activity").removeClass("activity");
    });
  });
  $(".offMenu").on("click", function(e) {
    $(".mobile_menu_container").removeClass("loaded");
    $(".mobile_menu_overlay").fadeOut(function() {
      $(".mobile_menu_container .loaded").removeClass("loaded");
      $(".mobile_menu_container .activity").removeClass("activity");
    });

  });
})
```